# JQuery FadeIn with every 2nd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I'm trying to create a Burgermenu, an easy dropdown without any animations.

After this I tried to let this dropdown fade in on click with the following script:

```
<script>
$('span.nav-button').click(function(){
console.log("information: click!");
$(".burgermenu").fadeIn(500);
});
</script>
```

Because of this I can no longer close the menu, the menu tries now to fadeIn every time.

Can someone show me a way to fade this class only on the second time I click the menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use .toggle() method:

```
$('span.nav-button').click(function(){
    $(".burgermenu").toggle();
});
```

Just use the toggle method

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('span.nav-button').click(function (){
        $('ul.burgermenu').toggle(500);$
    })
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ( $(window).width() > 400 ) {
            $('ul.burgermenu').removeAttr('style');
        }
    })
</script>
```

Lol i got toggle already above, so i just added the milliseconds xD -

thank u so much! =D